# "Refreshing" JQuery datepicker widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to refresh a datepicker widget. If a user presses for instance "button 1", the datepicker should have a certain set of properties, whereas if he presses "button 2" the datepicker should have a different set of properties.

How can i achieve this?

Some proof of concept code an be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/5zyLg/1/

```
$("#booking_calendar").datepicker({ 
    autoSize: false, 
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    altField: "#date",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "2W"
 );

 // VIRTUAL CLICK EVENT GOES HERE

$("#booking_calendar").datepicker({ 
    autoSize: false, 
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    altField: "#date",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "3W"
 );
 $("#booking_calendar").datepicker("refresh");
```

^this is the general idea, although it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`option` command](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option) to change a setting

```
 $("#booking_calendar").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', '10W');
```

---

And instead of using 1 and 2 and creating an `if` in your code which might get complicate if more options are added, use a `data` attribute that states the weeks

```
<div class="booking_search_cat lightgrey active" data-weeks="2W">
    <p>Group room</p>
</div>
<div class="booking_search_cat lightgrey" data-weeks="10W">
    <p>Lecture room</p>
</div>
```

and use

```
 $("#booking_calendar").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).data('weeks') );
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5zyLg/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try the 'refresh' method: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "refresh" );
```

Comment: This does not seem to refresh anything at all. I have tried to put it after and before the definition of the datepicker. Any suggestions?

Comment: You also have to change the properties that you want to change before doing the refresh method. It would be easier if you posted the code you have, maybe a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it made it a lot more clear. In that case take a look at Gaby aka G. Petrioli's answer below. Using the 'option' command, and it seems you then won't have to use the refresh method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to refresh the datepicker widget or set a different value to the widget based on button press? I am assuming a different value based on button press since you mention "datepicker should have a certain set of properties"

In such a scenario use

`$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );`

Ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Comment: Not exactly. I want maxDate to be "2W" or "10W" depending on which button is active.